# PyQt5 and pycharm unresolve references?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

So I installed pycharm and PyQt5 with python3.5.1 on mac.

Things are running. The codes compile too but I'm getting the unresolved references just like the other posts.

[image]

[image]

I tried to add the path in the python interpreter under preferences,
refresh the path and invalidate the caches but nothing works for me.

Can anyone point me into a direction to make it works? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see `PyQt5` in **Project Interpreter**?

Comment: Yeah, and I use virtualenv pip3 to install pyqt5

Comment: I uploaded an image so you can see. :)

Comment: Where did you find the code with these imports?

Comment: The imports codes are in my documents/codes folder. I created a new folder and use virtualenv to install python3 and pyqt5

Comment: What do you mean? the codes actually run and the application works. It's just pycharm showing the unresolved message and there isn't auto completion. What I am trying to do is to fix the auto completion.

Comment: What happen if you do only `import PyQt5`

Comment: The imports work fine by me with pycharm. hmm..

Comment: nevermind then, maybe i should reinstall it.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I tried to reinstall but it didn't work..

Comment: yes, whatche need?

Comment: @crey4fun See the answer below