# PyCharm complaining about unresolved reference for PyQt5

Tags: pycharm, pyqt5

PyCharm 2017.3 Community Edition, Windows 7 64, Anaconda 64-bit

I've created a virtual environment in Anaconda for Python 3.5.4. In Pycharm *Settings > Project > Project Interpreter* is set to this virtual environment. Using the + button on the Project Interpreter page I've installed PyQt5.

[image]

When I import anything from PyQt5, PyCharm complains about unresolved references and autocomplete does not work for PyQt5 methods/classes.

[image]

I installed **qtpy** module and I faced the same problem with some methods.

[image]

I tried `import PyQt5`and it doesn't complain about unresolved references, but I don't get autocomplete. The script runs fine though.

[PyCharm can't resolve references to PyQT5 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824942/pycharm-cant-resolve-references-to-pyqt5-modules/43825060#43825060) seems to provide a solution, but I'm not sure how to install a module **within PyCharm**.

PS: I understand that this might be a duplicate of some existing question but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Python version in the virtual environment that I was using for this project was 2.7.4, even though I had created a virenv for Python 3.5.4. So I updated Python for this environment to 3.5.4 and unresolved references errors went away and autocomplete works correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Hope this my *one stop answer* saved your day

***possible duplicate:***

**6 years, 9 months ago**

> [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code?rq=1)

**2 years, 11 months ago**

> [PyQt5 and pycharm unresolve references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587125/pyqt5-and-pycharm-unresolve-references?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**1 year, 11 months ago**

> [PyCharm can't resolve references to PyQT5 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824942/pycharm-cant-resolve-references-to-pyqt5-modules/43825060#43825060)

This answer based my experience today:

I've tried many installation of `PyQt5` from **cmd** and although all installation has successful but unresolved reference always happen:

[Unresolved reference 'QApplication'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfiN4.png)

i've tried a lot, down grade and up grade versions of PyQt5 from **cmd** like:

```
-pip install PyQt5==5.10
-pip uninstall PyQt-sip==4.9.8
-pip install PyQt-sip==4.9.7
-pip install PyQt5-tools==4.9.0.1.2
```

The command line or **cmd** never give me a solution. One Solution is **install a module within PyCharm.** It works like a charm. This is the complete tutorial

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

but i will repat it again here based my experiance:

**First** i cannot and always fail when installing `PyQt5` within **PyCharm**. It's happen maybe because i use **PyCharm** *Version 2017.3.3* so i upgrade the *version to 2018.3.6* because *2019.3* not support **32bit**, i use **32bit** by the way.

**Second** i upgrade Python from *3.6.4* to ***3.7.3***

**Last** i installing `PyQt5` within **PyCharm**.

```
File -> Settings -> Project:mypackage --> Project interpreter --> plus toggle
```

[installing PyQt5 within PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4DoD.jpg)

[installing PyQt5 within PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H1ii.jpg)

not like before, the installation of `PyQt5` within **PyCharm** now Successful. But something happen, you know what? Unresolved reference `QApplication` or `QtWidgets` still happen. Oh maaaaan! I confuse, what wrong with my computer, i see from tutorial youtube `PyQt5` installation run smoothly. Ok, i should looking the way, it should be easy. So i decided to Install All `PyQt5` module which i checklist blue on the image below even upgrade all to the very very latest version:

[upgrade all to the latest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piLm4.jpg)

under my deadline,

Unresolved reference `QApplication` solved.

Unresolved reference `QtWidgets` solved

i have read how to solved this issue manually,

> [Error installing PyQt5 library: unresolved reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854809/error-installing-pyqt5-library-unresolved-reference)

but the step too long. And finally within **PyCharm** installation is the pretty simple solution. This final result, work like a charm:

[Unresolved reference 'QtWidgets' solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFtO1.jpg)