# Error installing PyQt5 library: unresolved reference

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a browser using Python and the library PyQt5

I installed correctly the library but i don't know why components can't be found.
Is there a reason why the components can't be found? Thank you in advance

This is my code

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser


class MyBrowser(QWebPage):
''' Settings for the browser.'''

def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
    ''' Returns a User Agent that will be seen by the website. '''
    return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"


class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
       # QWebView
       self.view = QWebView.__init__(self)
       # self.view.setPage(MyBrowser())
       self.setWindowTitle('Loading...')
       self.titleChanged.connect(self.adjustTitle)
       # super(Browser).connect(self.ui.webView,QtCore.SIGNAL("titleChanged 
(const QString&)"), self.adjustTitle)

   def load(self, url):
       self.setUrl(QUrl(url))

   def adjustTitle(self):
       self.setWindowTitle(self.title())

   def disableJS(self):
      settings = QWebSettings.globalSettings()
      settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, False)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = Browser()
view.showMaximized()
view.load("https://pythonspot.com")
app.exec_()
```

This is where i get the error "Unresolved reference"
[image: This]

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5 *correctly*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to uninstall it from cmd:

```
pip uninstall pyqt5
```

then install it again:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

if it still not working try this method:

1) Install the binary file `Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 500 MB)` from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

2) Get `sip-4.14.7` (development snapshot) from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download).

3) Extract the file and open the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012`.

4) Execute these commands (in sip folder):

```
python configure.py
nmake
nmake install
```

5) Get the `pyQt5` from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download5).

6) Extract the file and open the `VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`.

7) Execute these commands:

```
python configure.py
```

I try it before and work for me